# How do I make sure one control is prioritized over another in a StackLayout in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
  <SearchBar Placeholder="Search"
             FontSize="Medium"
             HeightRequest="50"/>
  <ImageButton Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" Source="filter.png" MinimumWidthRequest="27" Margin="0,13,0,13" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></ImageButton>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my XAML code to display a searchbar on the left, and an image button on the right. I want the image button to take up as much space as it needs to display properly, but I don't know how to do that. This is in Xamarin Forms, so cross platform, for iOS and Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Never try to fix SearchBar width other wise in tab it's create problem

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SearchBar
                FontSize="Medium"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Placeholder="Search" />
            <ImageButton
                Margin="0,13,0,13"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                MinimumWidthRequest="27"
                Source="star.png" />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: It's working on android, but not iOS... On iOS the search bar just takes up the whole row

Comment: @chung You can try to create a custom `SearchBar` with  `Grid`(contails`Imageview` and `Entry`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SearchBar
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                FontSize="Medium"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Placeholder="Search" />
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,13,0,13"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                MinimumWidthRequest="27"
                Source="star.png" />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify a fixed width for the first control, and for the second use `HorizonalOptions="FillAndExpand"`

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
  <SearchBar WidthRequest="200" Placeholder="Search"
             FontSize="Medium"
             HeightRequest="50"/>
  <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" Source="filter.png" MinimumWidthRequest="27" Margin="0,13,0,13" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></ImageButton>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: What "units" is the WidthRequest measured in? I tried it, and it would look good at "400" an iPhone, but it would look super weird for an iPad for example. Could I maybe set a WidthRequest for the ImageButton and then fill and expand for the searchbar instead or does it have to be the one listed first that sets the width?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05